# img src equal to parent div's sibling img src

Tags: jquery

`.thumb-img`'s `src` should be equal to closest `.slider-img`'s `src`

```js
$(function imgsrc() {
  var thumbimg = $('.thumb-img')
    .closest('div')
    .prev()
    .attr('src');
  $('.thumb-img').attr('src', thumbimg)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img class="slider-img" data-u="image" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*H-25KB7EbSHjv70HXrdl6w.png" />
  <div data-u="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" data-u="thumb" src="" />
    <div class="ti">Slide Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: Your code works: what is not working?

Comment: Oh yes, really! It's working. This code is the part of gallery section in website. There it is not working. I'll share the link of full web site ASAP.

Comment: It is not working here the first image in gallery. The expanded image is displaying. But the img under it which should be taken from it is not displaying. In browser's code view it is showing that the src is unknown https://webeonmail.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have multiple img tags like this, in that case it won't work as you expected since variable `thumbimg` would be always first img tags value.

Because `$('.thumb-img').closest('div').prev()` would be a collection of img tags and [`.attr('src')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) always returns attribute first element in the cllection.

[*As per docs :*](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

---

In order to fix this issue, you have to iterate over the elements and then do the same individually for each element. So use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to achieve this.

```js
$(function imgsrc() {
  $('.thumb-img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).closest('div')
      .prev()
      .attr('src'));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img class="slider-img" data-u="image" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*H-25KB7EbSHjv70HXrdl6w.png" />
  <div data-u="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" data-u="thumb" src="" />
    <div class="ti">Slide Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or you can use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method with a callback(which iterate internally) as the second argument, within the callback get the `src` attribute of parent sibling element(`this` refers to the current element).

```js
$(function imgsrc() {
  $('.thumb-img').attr('src', function() {
    return $(this).closest('div')
      .prev()
      .attr('src');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img class="slider-img" data-u="image" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*H-25KB7EbSHjv70HXrdl6w.png" />
  <div data-u="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" data-u="thumb" src="" />
    <div class="ti">Slide Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** I just checked your website(as in comment), the structure is entirely different so you have to change something. Get ancestor div which contains the img tag with `slider-img` class, then get img tag and it's src attribute value.

```js
$(function imgsrc() {
  $('.thumb-img').attr('src', function() {
    return $(this).closest('div:has(.slider-img)')
      .find('.slider-img')
      .attr('src');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img class="slider-img" data-u="image" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*H-25KB7EbSHjv70HXrdl6w.png" />
  <div data-u="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" data-u="thumb" src="" />
    <div class="ti">Slide Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In separate code it works. But it is not working here, the first image in gallery. The expanded image is displaying. But the img under it which should be taken from it is not displaying. In browser's code view it is showing that the src is unknown. Please, look at it webeonmail.000webhostapp.com

Comment: @Bakhrom : sure

Comment: @Bakhrom  try ... `$(function imgsrc() {
    $('.thumb-img').attr('src', function() {
      return $(this).closest('div:has(.slider-img)')
        .find('.slider-img')
        .attr('src');
    })
  });`

Comment: @Bakhrom can u reproduce the problem in stacksnippet or jsfiddle?